# How prove this $f(n)=a_{n}$ for any $n\in Z^{+}$ ,then $k$ is positive integers

Tags: polynomials

> let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$,such $$a_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=1+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k$$where $k$ is real numbers,

show that:

> there is exsit polynomial $f(x)$, such for any $n\in Z^{+}$,always have
> $f(n)=a_{n}\Longleftrightarrow k\in Z^{+}$

my try: if $k$ is positive integer,then
$$a_{n}=1+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k$$ is postive integers,and is polynomial with degree $n$,so
let $$f(x)=x^k+(x-1)^k+\cdots+2^k+1^k$$

But if for any $n\in Z^{+}$,then exsit the polynomial $f(x)$ have
$f(n)=1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$

How prove $k$ is positive integers?

Thank you very much![image]

**please @ Ivan Loh and so on help.because I think  This is interesing problem!**

Comment: Interesting problem +1

Comment: Your attempt does not work: What is the polynomial that you mean, when $k=1$? $1+2+\dots+x$ does not make sense if $x$ in not an integer, while if $x$ is an integer, then it is not clear it is a polynomial, which is precisely what you need to show. You may want to look up [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Sums_of_pth_powers). (This still leaves pending the issue that $f$ is polynomial only when $k$ is a positive integer.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo,Hello,my problem is exsit polynomial $f(x)$,the $f(x)$ ：http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $k\neq -1$. Note that $\frac{a_n}{n^{k+1}}$ is a Riemann sum associated
to $g(t)=t^k$ for $t\in [0,1]$ (thanks to Daniel Fischer for pointing
this to me).  So it converges to $\int_{0}^1 g(t)dt=\frac{1}{k+1}$.

So we have $a_n \sim \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$ when $n\to\infty$. If $a_n$ is polynomial
in $n$, this implies that $k+1$ is a nonnegative integer, and we are done.

Finally, if $k=-1$ we have the harmonic series which is well-known to be
asymptotically equivalent to ${\sf log}(n)$, which increases slower than
any polynomial.

Comment: why $a_{n}$ is polynomial in $n$,that implies that $k+1$ is a nonngative integer?

Comment: Because if $a_n$ is polynomial with degree $d$, say $a_n=c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2+\ldots +c_dn^d$, then $a_n \sim c_nn^d $ when $n\to \infty$. So we must have $c_dn^d \sim \frac{n^(k+1)}{k+1}$ when $n\to \infty$, and this forces $d=k+1$.